# SMTP: Connection Refused error

Tags: magento-1.9, email, smtp, connection

I am building my ecommerce store in Magento 1.9.4. I have installed **Ashroder SMTP Pro** extension manually through FTP. It installed successfully. I have done RUN SHELL test but I am getting connection refused error. I have attached the screenshot. I am using Custom SMTP option & used my email login & password that I purchased from my hosting account, please confirm is it correct. Also confirm the info I have filled is correct. Please help me in this concern. New error is coming. Please take a look.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom SMTP is only used for your localhost’s SMTP. If you want to use Google SMTP, select Google in the Email connection.

Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Select Google Apps or Gmail. That's the first option before Custom SMTP.

Comment: How to do that? Pleas explain in details.

Comment: In the E-mail Connection option, select Google/Gmail instead of Custom SMTP. I added a screenshot above for your reference.

Comment: Only I have to select Google mail and to keep other field blank

Comment: After selecting Google Apps or SMTP. Just enter your Google Apps e-mail and password. It should work. :D

If you're using custom SMTP, the host should be the IP address of your mailserver.

May I know what webhosting company you're using?

Comment: I am using GoDaddy

Comment: It is showing error now by using Custom SMTP. I have attached new screenshot. Please check.

Comment: How to fix this @Bryan Veloso

Comment: You need to turn authentication ON, then enter the username and password for your email. 

Comment: Did you create an email inside GoDaddy panel? Or not yet?

Comment: And also, according to the error above. You might have not installed it properly. O__O. DB tables are missing.

Comment: I have support@cravestore.in as a email from GoDaddy.

Comment: You should setup an email account in the server via cPanel. Did you do that yet? 

Comment: As I told u this is my email that I setup from GoDaddy account support@cravestore.in

Comment: Any answer @Bryan Veloso

Comment: That won't work. You need to set it up in your cpanel 

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: How to do that can you explain @bryan.

Comment: Do you have access to your cpanel? To to mail, then add a new account in the mail inside your cpanel. :)

Comment: I have already done that. My mail id of cpanel is support@cravestore.in. what to do next?